# How to pass state from one component to another that are joined by a stacknavigator in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have two components, A and B that are joined together by the stack navigator that are being rendered in App.js. Now in A I have declared some state variables and also in B I have declared some state variables. I want to use the state variables I declared in A in B. And then use all the state variables of A and B together to test an api endpoint.

For e.g: Componenet A:

```
...
const A = () => {
  const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState("");
  const [projectDescription, setProjectDescription] = useState("");
  const [projectBudget, setProjectBudget] = useState(null);
  const [projectDuration, setProjectDuration] = useState(null);
  const [industry, setIndustry] = useState("");
  const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState("");
  const [numberOfEmployees, setNumberOfEmployees] = useState(null);

  return (
   ...
  );
}

...
```

```
  ...
  const B = () => {

  var newDiamond = [
  { newCriteria: { novelty: "", technology: "", complexity: "", pace: "" } },
  ];
  ...
  const [techVal, setTechVal] = useState("");
  const [noveltyVal, setNoveltyVal] = useState("");
  const [complexityVal, setComplexityVal] = useState("");
  const [paceVal, setPaceVal] = useState("");

  return (
   ...
    newDiamond[0].newCriteria.technology = techVal;
   ...
    newDiamond[0].newCriteria.novelty = noveltyVal;
   ...
    newDiamond[0].newCriteria.complexity = complexityVal;
   ...
    newDiamond[0].newCriteria.pace = paceVal;
   ...
   //Need to initiate an HTTP request here by using state variables of both A and B components:
   axios.post('/projects', {projectName, projectDescription, projectBudget, projectDuration, industry, companyName, numberOfEmployees, newDiamond});
  //newDiamond that is initialized in B uses state variables of B, is used in the request.
   ...
  );
}
...
```

How can I pass state from A to B? I don't think there is a parent-child relationship between them so I don't think I can pass props b/w them.

Comment: I think you need some storage, try to use redux or localStorage to store values

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using React Context API https://uk.reactjs.org/docs/context.html. Its dedicated to sharing the common state (`items` in your case). Here is an example:
You should create a common context for items:
ItemsState.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

const ItemsContext = React.createContext([]);

export const ItemsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ItemsContext.Provider value={useState([])}>
      {children}
    </ItemsContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useItems = () => useContext(ItemsContext);
```

Then share the context between screens with provider in App.js like this

```
import {ItemsProvider} from 'ItemsState';

function App() {
  return (
   <ItemsProvider> // share the items between both screens
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Add" component={AddScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
   </ItemsProvider>
  );
}
```

Then use items context in each screen like this AddScreen.js

```
import {useItems} from './ItemsState';

function AddScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const [items, setItems] = useItems(); // <- using items context as global useState
  const [itemName, setItemName] = React.useState('');
  const [itemPrice, setItemPrice] = React.useState('0');

  const addItem = () => {
    setItems([...items, { itemName, itemPrice }]);
    setItemName('');
    setItemPrice('0');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder="What's on your mind?"
        value={itemName}
        onChangeText={setItemName}
      />
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder="What's on your mind?"
        value={itemPrice}
        onChangeText={setItemPrice}
      />
      <Button
        title="Done"
        onPress={() => {
          addItem();
          // Pass params back to home screen
          navigation.navigate('Home', items);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can also use `useReducer` hook and make more Redux-like. Check out this article
https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c